# How to delete a forms django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I just wish my delete button deletes the form to a specific id

for now I can remove all items but i have an error :

```
'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

> My views.py

```
def delete_champs(request, instance):
    #+some code to check if this object belongs to the logged in user
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    if logged_user:
        form = ChampsForm(request.GET, instance=Champs.objects.get(pk=instance).delete())
        if form.is_valid():
            form.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/champs') # wherever to go after deleting
        else:
            form = DeleteNewForm(instance=Champs.objects.get(pk=instance))
            return render(request, 'polls/delete_champs.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = DeleteNewForm(instance=Champs.objects.get(pk=instance))
        form.delete()

        return render(request, 'polls/delete_champs.html', {'form': form})
```

> my forms.py

```
class ChampsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Champs
        fields = ('champs','contenu')


class DeleteNewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Champs
        fields = ['champs','contenu']
```

> my models.py

```
class Champs(models.Model):
    champs = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contenu = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I have an error in my views but i don't know what ! 
What is the method for delete an object ?

[image: This is the result with button delete]

Comment: You are using something that doesn't even exist in django, like `form.delete()`. What makes you think that would work? Also what do you mean to delete a form?

Comment: But that said, the problem does not appear to be related to deletion at all. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but one should **NEVER** delete (nor update or create etc) on a GET request. GET is for reading resources and MUST be idempotent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to be the cause of the problem:

```
form = ChampsForm(request.GET, instance=Champs.objects.get(pk=instance).delete())
```

Basically, you pass the result of the [`Model.delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete) method as an instance. It returns a tuple, and that's clearly not what you want. Instead you should pass the actual object, not its deletion's result:

```
form = ChampsForm(request.GET, instance=Champs.objects.get(pk=instance))
```